# Ventilate value year to all months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

| Country | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2020 | 1200 |
| GE | 2020 | 2400 |

I want to ventilate the value of the year over all the months (value year / 12)

| Country | Year | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 2020 | 1 | 100 |
| US | 2020 | 2 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| GE | 2020 | 1 | 200 |

Comment: Generate numbers table with the values from 1 to 12 and join it.

Comment: @MarkD The question deals with SQL programming, not with DBMS administration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ventilate" ? Did you perhaps mean "distribute" ?
Also, please add an actual question like "How can I distribute Value column of my table to another table where each row would be 1/12th of the value?"

Comment: what do you want to happen if the initial value is not evenly divisible by 12?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate months using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive months as (
      select 1 as month
      union all
      select month + 1
      from months
      where month < 12
    )
select t.country, t.year, m.month, t.value / 12
from t cross join
     months m;
```

You can also use an existing tally table.  Or a derived table that lists out the values:

```
select *
from t cross join
     (select 1 as month union all
      select 2 as month union all
      . . .
     ) m
```